# What is meant by Editable and Queryable when designing against a database?

Tags: c#, database-design, database-connection

I'm having a problem in understanding what is meant by "Editable" and "Queryable" in designing the application behavior to interact with the database.

These two terms gets attached to a lot of types, such as, Editable Procedure, Queryable Repository or Editable Service.

Can someone please explain with examples?

Thanks.

Comment: Editable - can be edited. Queryable - can be queried. I would think that would be obvious to anyone with a basic knowledge of the English language...

Comment: You probably need to quote some complete sentences with these phrases in them, to give us more context.

Comment: I googled for those terms and this question came up as the first hit. I don't think they're very common.

Comment: MVC DI Example: Controller -> Editable Service -> Editable Repository -> Editable Procedure -> Database.

I also google the terms and they are not widely used. I'm analyzing an application and these two terms are very ambiguous.